# Deallocate all memory in a container of pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, container

I want to erase all memory in a container. Currently I'm using this :

```
template<typename Cont>
void clear_mem(Cont &container)
{
    while (!container.empty())
    {
        delete container.back();
        container.pop_back();
    }
}
```

1. Should the operation of deleting the memory held by the contents be separated by clearing the container ?
2. Is it pointless to make this function a template, since it can only  operate on vector and list ?

Comment: Why are you putting pointers in your containers?

Comment: If you really need a container full of pointers, where the container owns what the pointers point at, you probably want to look into Boost [`ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Answer (score 10):

This assumes that the container holds raw pointer and it owns the pointers. it is a better idea to then let the container hold smart pointers.

These will automatically clear the object they hold when they get destroyed (using `delete` by default).

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Type> Type_ptr;
std::vector<Type_ptr> container;
```

and use emplace to fill it;

```
container.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Type>());
```

Comment: no raw `new`, please use `container.emplace_back(make_unique<Type>());` instead.

Comment: @TemplateRex good suggestion! Unfortunately, this is not supported by all compilers yet, since it was only introduced in C++ 14 (C++ 11 has only `make_shared`)

Comment: @lethal-guitar I know, but even so, writing your own `make_unique` (or copy the one from the Standard proposal) in that case is better than raw `new`.

Answer (score 3):

### Question 1

It depends. An **std::vector** won't actually release any underlying buffer memory even if it's no longer required, so you can't rely on removing the elements in order to free the memory used to store them.

e.g

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

vec.clear();

//vec still owns a buffer large enough to hold its initial elements
```

Well, you could now reasonably say that "ok, no problem! I'll just use **std::vector::resize**". The problem with this method is that it only resizes the buffer when the requested size is bigger than the buffer's current size.

In order to free the memory allocated by the std::vector itself, the **swap idiom** is used, where you construct a new empty vector and you swap it with the original.

Continuing from the previous example

```
std::vector<int> empty{};
vec.swap(empty);
```

**std::list** also has a **swap** method, so implementing a template function that works for both using the swap idiom is possible, even though you don't need it for a list because the node used to store an element is released when its removed.

A more C++/STL way to do it would be

```
template<template<typename ElementType, typename Alloc> 
         class    ContType, 
         typename ElementType,
         typename Alloc>
void clear_mem(ContType<ElementType*, Alloc>& container)
{
    std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), [](ElementType* element) {
        delete element;
    });

    ContType<ElementType*, Alloc> empty{};
    container.swap(empty);
}
```

Of course such an implementation would only work for a container holding pointers to objects.

To conclude, releasing the underlying memory while removing elements is not possible with **std::vector**.

### Question 2

No it's not, it very common to swap std::list for std::vector and vice versa, so using a template deleter would not break client code when a change actually happens.

Comment: std::vector has a `shrink_to_fit()` so you don't need to swap it around (since C++11)

Comment: @ratchetfreak According to the C++ standard it's not mandatory for `shrink_to_fit` to actually fulfil the request. Also the template won't work for an `std::list`.